# Inductive vs Transductive Learning

Tags: semi-supervised-learning

I am reading about Inductive and Transductive Learning.

Some of the questions that come to mind are the following:

1. What is the difference between these two?
2. Which algorithms are usually employed for these methods?
3. Why would someone choose the latter over the former?
4. What are the best Python packages that implement these methods?

I have some answers to these questions, but I prefer to survey information from other people who have worked on semi-supervised learning problems for some time.